# Pass String Variable to Function Argument as Comma Separated List

Tags: powershell, parameter-passing

I've got a PowerShell function that accepts multiple values for a single argument via a comma separated list, like so:

```
test-function -Targets 127.0.0.1, 8.8.8.8, fake.fqdn.com -FileName "c:\results.csv"
```

Here is the param section:

```
function test-function {
    param(
        [string[]]$Targets
        [string]$FileName
    )
}
```

I'm trying to put an array in as multiple Target arguments, so I've put them into a single variable like so:

```
foreach ($target in $arrayTargets) { $temp = $temp + ", $Target" }
$Targets = $temp -replace "^, ", ""
```

This would result in the required "127.0.0.1, 8.8.8.8, fake.fqdn.com" as a string in the variable `$Targets`.

When I try to execute the function referencing the `$Targets` variable, the function interprets `$Targets` as if it's a single entry, not multiple.  This is what I've tried with the same results:

```
test-function -Targets $Targets -FileName "c:\results.csv"
test-function -Targets "$Targets" -FileName "c:\results.csv"
```

I've also tried an ArgList several different ways:

```
$ArgList = "-Targets $Targets -FileName `"c:\results.csv`""
test-function $ArgList
```

Instead of taking each individual array entry as an argument, it takes the entire string as the argument.

How can I get this function to accept an array as multiple targets?

Comment: FYI your function call and function definitions use different parameter names. This could be confusing for someone trying to read what is going on here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have an array of arguments, there should be no reason to pack them into a string to pass to your function.  Simply pass the array.

```
test-function -Targets $arrayTargets
```

To assign an array of values to a variable in PowerShell, simply assign a comma-separated list.  Note to make an array of strings, you should make sure to put the strings in quotes (single or double).  All of the following are equivalent.

```
$arr = @("127.0.0.1", "8.8.8.8", "fake.fqdn.com")
$arr = ('127.0.0.1', '8.8.8.8', 'fake.fqdn.com')
$arr = "127.0.0.1", '8.8.8.8', "fake.fqdn.com"
```

If you need your array to convert to a comma-separated string for any reason, there's no need to build it with a `foreach` loop.  Instead use the `-join` operator.

```
PS> $string = $arr -join ', '
PS> $string
127.0.0.1, 8.8.8.8, fake.fqdn.com
```

But you will probably only want your array in this form to display it.  As shown above, it's best to keep it in array form to pass to a function.  You can even get the array back from the string using the `-split` operator.

```
PS> $string -split ', '
127.0.0.1
8.8.8.8
fake.fqdn.com
```

Comment: Yeup!  This fixed my problem.