# Powershell - How to pass a two values for a array variable

Tags: arrays, powershell, hyper-v

Msvm_GuestNetworkAdapterConfiguration class accepts DNSServers in string array

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hyperv_v2/msvm-guestnetworkadapterconfiguration

I have the data in the CSV to populate

```
Set-VMNetworkConfiguration -IPAddress $sipaddress -Subnet $netmask -DNSServers $dns -DefaultGateway $gateway
```

how to pass the two variables read from CSV to the variable DNSServers on the command?

The module Set-VMNetworkConfiguration accepts value as

```
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,
  Position=4,
  ParameterSetName='Static')]
 [String[]]$DNSServers = @(),
```

sample to pass

```
site,ipaddress,netmask,gateway,dns1,dns2
1234,172.28.158.122,255.255.255.240,172.28.158.113,172.28.158.113,172.28.158.113
5678,172.28.158.123,255.255.255.240,172.28.158.113,172.28.158.113,172.28.158.113
F06E,172.28.158.124,255.255.255.240,172.28.158.113,172.28.158.113,172.28,158.113
```

This following concatenation get to a

```
$dns = $($dns1[$index],$dns2[$index])
```

pass variable state

```
DEBUG:    1+  >>>> Get-VMNetworkAdapter -VMName packer-centos8-base-g2-1 | Set-VMNetworkConfiguration -IPAddress 172.28.158.124 -Subnet 255.255.255.240 -DNSServers 172.28.158.113 172.28.158.113 -DefaultGateway 172.28.158.113
```

Ends up with error saying

```
Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'NetworkAdapter'. Cannot convert the "172.28.158.113" value of type "System.String" to type "Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.VMNetworkAdapter".
```

pls guide

Comment: so ... the simple answer is to add the two IPs into an array. nothing more than that makes sense to discuss until you post a sample of the CSV. [*grin*] please, add it to the Question, not as a comment ... and use code formatting to make it readable.

Comment: this `-DNSServers 172.28.158.113 172.28.158.113` is not an array. the two items are delimited by a _SPACE_ ... and that makes the 2nd an entirely different parameter input. [*grin*] try using `-DNSServers '172.28.158.113', '172.28.158.113'` instead. note the comma between the two strings.

Comment: am a newbie to ps, any guide on getting this pattern on powershell, because this pattern $dns = $($dns1[$index],$dns2[$index]) didnt work

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37889252/pass-string-variable-to-function-argument-as-comma-separated-list) solved the issue

Comment: excellent! glad to know you got it working as needed ... and thanks for the "how" of it all. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error.

```
$dns = $($dns1[$index]),$($dns2[$index])
```

and you are missing a comma 
Edit: fixed comma.  Thank you for letting me know.

"-DNSServers 172.28.158.113 ,172.28.158.113"

```
Get-VMNetworkAdapter -VMName packer-centos8-base-g2-1 | Set-VMNetworkConfiguration -IPAddress 172.28.158.124 -Subnet 255.255.255.240 -DNSServers 172.28.158.113, 172.28.158.113 -DefaultGateway 172.28.158.113
```

Comment: True, you have replicated the problem, thanks a lot but i had sorted that issue with a -join to add a comma in btn a values in the array!